# Charging a battery bank with Solar Cells

Tags: wiring, solar-panels, solar, electronics

So essentially bought one of these "solar battery banks" for a weather station project i am working on. 
Long story short the power output for the built in cell is awful.
Now the question is, can I just hook up a bigger solar cell to a USB output and plug into the battery bank directly to charge it? For example;

Solar cell - usb - battery bank
rather than 
solar cell - charge controller - usb - battery bank

I know that these banks have their own internal charge controller so assuming I get a 5V output panel would this be ok?

Comment: This is probably a question that should be migrated to a more appropriate forum here at SE.  I dk how to do that.  But at any rate, DanFy, welcome to SE, please take the tour so you'll know how to best participate.   Take care.

Comment: Thank you, first post here so I wasn't entirely sure where to put it.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson just raise a custom flag on the question indicating it could use migration

Comment: You “know these cells have there own charge controller” why would you need a second one then? The model of the panel would be needed to provide helpful information , is the panel in full sun no shadows at all? 
Depending on the type of panel even a slight shadow can kill the output of the panel.